# java login/logout on localhost

Tags: java, authentication, logout, cardlayout

This is for a desktop application that uses `jdbc:mysql://localhost/` database.
Long story short, this is what i`m trying to do:

---

> 1. Ask for credentials (**Username/Password**).
> 2. Compare with **MySQL** database for match (**true/false**).
> 3. If **true** → load the workspace, which implements data from **MySQL**.
> 4. If **false** → keep asking for valid credentials.

---

As of now, i`m thinking of using **CardLayout** approach.
The schema is simple:

> 1. If **true** → switch to **`workspace_card`**.
>
>    - Set **MySQL** table field (`user_status`) to **1** (meaning **online**).
> 2. **Logout** → switch to **`login_card`**.
>
>    - Set **MySQL** table field (`user_status`) to **0** (meaning **offline**).

So, my question is:

> - May **CardLayout** be considered a good approach when it comes to  **low level security** type of applications?
> - What is the most accurate **schema/method** to use in **JavaWorld** to achieve the    above **tasks/results**?

Answer (score 0):

I guess stoting user online/offline status in database and manahe it through some application in very bad approach. In some cases, such of application/database  process shutdown, force shutdown and others, your logout logic may not be executed, and `user_status` will be left as online.

In typical java web application we usually use some web session (which one storing the credentials) and some JDBC pool (like [bonecp](http://jolbox.com/) or [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)). You have desktop application, so you  may use some JDBC pool and you need to make some kind of session to storing user status/credentials

Comment: Ok, but beside the pooling method and `user_status`, the use of **CardLayout** is considered acceptable by Java Developers ? I'm wondering since, the `login_card` is still running in the back. Or does it?